# How to stop `mail` action sending to `:to` address if :bcc addresses are empty in ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have a actinmailer method where the `@receiver` is populated if it matches certain conditions and there is a `@default_mail`. Which sends mails to receivers in BCC and default_mail in `to` field. It is as follows:

```
def mail_users
    @default_mail = "user@gmail.com"
    @latest_listing_mail= Equipment.joins(:user).last.user.email
    @wanted_req_mail = WantedEquipment.where(sub_category_id: "#{a}", status: 2).pluck(:email) 
    @wanted_req_mail.include? @latest_listing_mail
    if true
       @receiver = @wanted_req_mail.delete(@latest_listing_mail)
       @receiver = @wanted_req_mail
       mail(bcc: @receiver, to: @default_mail)
    end
end
```

I don't want the `mail` to perform if the `@receiver` is empty. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a condition

```
mail(bcc: @receiver, to: @default_mail) if @receiver.present?
```

And you might want to remove this condition

```
if true # doesn't make sense
end
```

Comment: I moved it out of `if true..end` condition and changed it to `mail(bcc: @receiver, to: @default_mail, subject: @subject) if @receiver`. It still delivering even when `@receiver` is empty.

Comment: Try adding present?   `if @receiver.present?`